# JQuery mobile vs Phone Gap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I want to convert an existing website for mobile version, what will be the best choice for me.

- Using JQuery Mobile on asp.net webform or asp.net mvc
- Create application on phonegap for the targeted mobiles
- Any Other ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to provide a lot more information about your goals and your background to answer the best solution for you.

However, I can clarify your title: PhoneGap is a complementary solution to jQuery Mobile. They provide different capabilities and work together. You can use one or both of them. Here's a [picture](https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AUAW8A21x9KEZGhqazRtaGpfMjAzZ2hwaHYyOGc&hl=en_US).

PhoneGap does two major functions:

- Converts JavaScript/HTML/CSS assets to a native app
- Provides a set of JavaScript APIs that map to device capabilities, not otherwise accessible to a web app, like Contacts, Accelerometer, Telephony, GPS, etc

jQuery Mobile is a cross-platform user interface system. It is an extension to jQuery that provides a set of UI libraries specialized for mobile device programming including small screens and touch and swipe events.